# How to delete entries from a Javascript Array of nested objects given the condition that the last level in the tree is undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, recursion, filter

I've been trying to filter an array of objects using recursion and javascript. I was able to recursively transform the initial JSON I get from an API (more than 5k lines) down to the data I need but I seem to be unable to filter out the undefined entries. Below is a sample of the object I am trying clean.

The idea is to have only the entries whose innermost child member does not only contain a parent, you can see this in the element whose innermost child has the name "loan". The level these childs can appear are not fixed as well as how many of them at a time.

```
{
    "root": [
        {
            "parent": {
                "parentId": null,
                "parentName": null
            },
            "child": [
                {
                    "parent": {
                        "parentId": "1000641",
                        "parentName": "parent120"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "parent": {
                        "parentId": "1000641",
                        "parentName": "parent121"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "parent": {
                "parentId": null,
                "parentName": null
            }
        },
        {
            "parent": {
                "parentId": null,
                "parentName": null
            },
            "child": [
                {
                    "parent": {
                        "parentId": "1000607",
                        "parentName": "parent122"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "parent": {
                        "parentId": "1000607",
                        "parentName": "parent123"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "parent": {
                        "parentId": "1000607",
                        "parentName": "parent124"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "parent": {
                "parentId": null,
                "parentName": null
            },
            "child": [
                {
                    "parent": {
                        "parentId": "1000604",
                        "parentName": "parent125"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "parent": {
                        "parentId": "1000604",
                        "parentName": "parent126"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "parent": {
                "parentId": null,
                "parentName": null
            },
            "child": [
                {
                    "parent": {
                        "parentId": "1000657",
                        "parentName": "parent127"
                    },
                    "child": [
                        {
                            "parent": {
                                "parentId": "1000529",
                                "parentName": "parent128"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "parent": {
                                "parentId": "1000529",
                                "parentName": "parent129"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "parent": {
                                "parentId": "1000529",
                                "parentName": "parent111"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "parent": {
                                "parentId": "1000529",
                                "parentName": "parent100"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "parent": {
                                "parentId": "1000529",
                                "parentName": "parent90"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "parent": {
                        "parentId": "1000657",
                        "parentName": "parent91"
                    },
                    "child": [
                        {
                            "parent": {
                                "parentId": "1000535",
                                "parentName": "parent92"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "parent": {
                                "parentId": "1000535",
                                "parentName": "parent92"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "parent": {
                                "parentId": "1000535",
                                "parentName": "parent92"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "parent": {
                                "parentId": "1000535",
                                "parentName": "parent92"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "parent": {
                        "parentId": "1000657",
                        "parentName": "parent234"
                    },
                    "child": [
                        {
                            "parent": {
                                "parentId": "1000524",
                                "parentName": "parent230"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "parent": {
                                "parentId": "1000524",
                                "parentName": "parent231"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "parent": {
                                "parentId": "1000524",
                                "parentName": "parent232"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "parent": {
                                "parentId": "1000524",
                                "parentName": "parent233"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "parent": {
                        "parentId": "1000657",
                        "parentName": "parent234"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "parent": {
                "parentId": null,
                "parentName": null
            }
        },
        {
            "parent": {
                "parentId": null,
                "parentName": null
            }
        },
        {
            "parent": {
                "parentId": null,
                "parentName": null
            }
        },
        {
            "parent": {
                "parentId": null,
                "parentName": null
            }
        },
        {
            "parent": {
                "parentId": null,
                "parentName": null
            },
            "child": [
                {
                    "parent": {
                        "parentId": "1000611",
                        "parentName": "loan parent"
                    },
                    "child": [
                        {
                            "parent": {
                                "parentId": "1000612",
                                "parentName": "loan"
                            },
                            "child": {
                                "name": "loan1",
                                "id": "1000613",
                                "treeDepth": 3
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "parent": {
                                "parentId": "1000612",
                                "parentName": "loan"
                            },
                            "child": {
                                "name": "loan2",
                                "id": "1000615",
                                "treeDepth": 3
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "parent": {
                                "parentId": "1000612",
                                "parentName": "loan"
                            },
                            "child": {
                                "name": "loan3",
                                "id": "1000614",
                                "treeDepth": 3
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "parent": {
                        "parentId": "1000611",
                        "parentName": "DIGI VAS CAY"
                    },
                    "child": [
                        {
                            "parent": {
                                "parentId": "1000616",
                                "parentName": "bundle1"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "parent": {
                                "parentId": "1000616",
                                "parentName": "bundle2"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "parent": {
                "parentId": null,
                "parentName": null
            },
            "child": [
                {
                    "parent": {
                        "parentId": "1000645",
                        "parentName": "parent6"
                    },
                    "child": [
                        {
                            "parent": {
                                "parentId": "1000646",
                                "parentName": "parent8"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "parent": {
                                "parentId": "1000646",
                                "parentName": "parent8"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "parent": {
                                "parentId": "1000646",
                                "parentName": "parent8"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "parent": {
                                "parentId": "1000646",
                                "parentName": "parent8"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "parent": {
                        "parentId": "1000645",
                        "parentName": "parent5"
                    },
                    "child": [
                        {
                            "parent": {
                                "parentId": "1000651",
                                "parentName": "parent6"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "parent": {
                                "parentId": "1000651",
                                "parentName": "parent6"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "parent": {
                        "parentId": "1000645",
                        "parentName": "parent5"
                    },
                    "child": [
                        {
                            "parent": {
                                "parentId": "1000654",
                                "parentName": "parent123"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "parent": {
                                "parentId": "1000654",
                                "parentName": "parent123"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried filtering with the following code with no avail

```
function deleteNoChildEntries(membersArray) {
  return membersArray.filter(function magic(element) {
    if(Array.isArray(element.child)) {
      element.child.filter(magic);
    }

    return element.child !== undefined;

  });
}
```

I expect to get an array with only one element containing the tree spaning the childs that exist and are not populated only by parents. Here's what I expect to get

```
[
        {
            "parent": {
                "parentId": null,
                "parentName": null
            },
            "child": [
                {
                    "parent": {
                        "parentId": "1000611",
                        "parentName": "loan parent"
                    },
                    "child": [
                        {
                            "parent": {
                                "parentId": "1000612",
                                "parentName": "loan"
                            },
                            "child": {
                                "name": "loan1",
                                "id": "1000613",
                                "treeDepth": 3
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "parent": {
                                "parentId": "1000612",
                                "parentName": "loan"
                            },
                            "child": {
                                "name": "loan2",
                                "id": "1000615",
                                "treeDepth": 3
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "parent": {
                                "parentId": "1000612",
                                "parentName": "loan"
                            },
                            "child": {
                                "name": "loan3",
                                "id": "1000614",
                                "treeDepth": 3
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

and here is what my code is doing

```
[
  {
    "parent": {
      "parentId": null,
      "parentName": null
    },
    "child": [
      {
        "parent": {
          "parentId": "1000641",
          "parentName": "parent120"
        }
      },
      {
        "parent": {
          "parentId": "1000641",
          "parentName": "parent121"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "parent": {
      "parentId": null,
      "parentName": null
    },
    "child": [
      {
        "parent": {
          "parentId": "1000607",
          "parentName": "parent122"
        }
      },
      {
        "parent": {
          "parentId": "1000607",
          "parentName": "parent123"
        }
      },
      {
        "parent": {
          "parentId": "1000607",
          "parentName": "parent124"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "parent": {
      "parentId": null,
      "parentName": null
    },
    "child": [
      {
        "parent": {
          "parentId": "1000604",
          "parentName": "parent125"
        }
      },
      {
        "parent": {
          "parentId": "1000604",
          "parentName": "parent126"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "parent": {
      "parentId": null,
      "parentName": null
    },
    "child": [
      {
        "parent": {
          "parentId": "1000657",
          "parentName": "parent127"
        },
        "child": [
          {
            "parent": {
              "parentId": "1000529",
              "parentName": "parent128"
            }
          },
          {
            "parent": {
              "parentId": "1000529",
              "parentName": "parent129"
            }
          },
          {
            "parent": {
              "parentId": "1000529",
              "parentName": "parent111"
            }
          },
          {
            "parent": {
              "parentId": "1000529",
              "parentName": "parent100"
            }
          },
          {
            "parent": {
              "parentId": "1000529",
              "parentName": "parent90"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "parent": {
          "parentId": "1000657",
          "parentName": "parent91"
        },
        "child": [
          {
            "parent": {
              "parentId": "1000535",
              "parentName": "parent92"
            }
          },
          {
            "parent": {
              "parentId": "1000535",
              "parentName": "parent92"
            }
          },
          {
            "parent": {
              "parentId": "1000535",
              "parentName": "parent92"
            }
          },
          {
            "parent": {
              "parentId": "1000535",
              "parentName": "parent92"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "parent": {
          "parentId": "1000657",
          "parentName": "parent234"
        },
        "child": [
          {
            "parent": {
              "parentId": "1000524",
              "parentName": "parent230"
            }
          },
          {
            "parent": {
              "parentId": "1000524",
              "parentName": "parent231"
            }
          },
          {
            "parent": {
              "parentId": "1000524",
              "parentName": "parent232"
            }
          },
          {
            "parent": {
              "parentId": "1000524",
              "parentName": "parent233"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "parent": {
          "parentId": "1000657",
          "parentName": "parent234"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "parent": {
      "parentId": null,
      "parentName": null
    },
    "child": [
      {
        "parent": {
          "parentId": "1000611",
          "parentName": "loan parent"
        },
        "child": [
          {
            "parent": {
              "parentId": "1000612",
              "parentName": "loan"
            },
            "child": {
              "name": "loan1",
              "id": "1000613",
              "treeDepth": 3
            }
          },
          {
            "parent": {
              "parentId": "1000612",
              "parentName": "loan"
            },
            "child": {
              "name": "loan2",
              "id": "1000615",
              "treeDepth": 3
            }
          },
          {
            "parent": {
              "parentId": "1000612",
              "parentName": "loan"
            },
            "child": {
              "name": "loan3",
              "id": "1000614",
              "treeDepth": 3
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "parent": {
          "parentId": "1000611",
          "parentName": "DIGI VAS CAY"
        },
        "child": [
          {
            "parent": {
              "parentId": "1000616",
              "parentName": "bundle1"
            }
          },
          {
            "parent": {
              "parentId": "1000616",
              "parentName": "bundle2"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "parent": {
      "parentId": null,
      "parentName": null
    },
    "child": [
      {
        "parent": {
          "parentId": "1000645",
          "parentName": "parent6"
        },
        "child": [
          {
            "parent": {
              "parentId": "1000646",
              "parentName": "parent8"
            }
          },
          {
            "parent": {
              "parentId": "1000646",
              "parentName": "parent8"
            }
          },
          {
            "parent": {
              "parentId": "1000646",
              "parentName": "parent8"
            }
          },
          {
            "parent": {
              "parentId": "1000646",
              "parentName": "parent8"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "parent": {
          "parentId": "1000645",
          "parentName": "parent5"
        },
        "child": [
          {
            "parent": {
              "parentId": "1000651",
              "parentName": "parent6"
            }
          },
          {
            "parent": {
              "parentId": "1000651",
              "parentName": "parent6"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "parent": {
          "parentId": "1000645",
          "parentName": "parent5"
        },
        "child": [
          {
            "parent": {
              "parentId": "1000654",
              "parentName": "parent123"
            }
          },
          {
            "parent": {
              "parentId": "1000654",
              "parentName": "parent123"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have set up a code pen for testing https://codepen.io/mathSychs/pen/eYbmwLp

Comment: If you turn the object into an array you can map through the objects and then convert them back if you make a codepen with some dummy data I think I can help you

Comment: Could you show the output array from above example

Comment: *"only the entries whose innermost child member does not only contain a parent"*: It seems to me that *all* innermost child members only contain a parent key. So you want an empty object as result?

Comment: @Wayne I have set up a code pen and added some more information for what has been tried and what is expectedat the output

Comment: You need to simplify the input and output so we can clearly see what is expected. You are giving us a lot of excess data.

Answer (score 1):

The [`JSON.parse` reviver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#using_the_reviver_parameter) and [`JSON.stringify` replacer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#the_replacer_parameter) can be used to process nested values :

```js
const json = '{"root":[{"parent":{"parentId":null,"parentName":null},"child":[{"parent":{"parentId":"1000641","parentName":"parent120"}},{"parent":{"parentId":"1000641","parentName":"parent121"}}]},{"parent":{"parentId":null,"parentName":null}},{"parent":{"parentId":null,"parentName":null},"child":[{"parent":{"parentId":"1000607","parentName":"parent122"}},{"parent":{"parentId":"1000607","parentName":"parent123"}},{"parent":{"parentId":"1000607","parentName":"parent124"}}]},{"parent":{"parentId":null,"parentName":null},"child":[{"parent":{"parentId":"1000604","parentName":"parent125"}},{"parent":{"parentId":"1000604","parentName":"parent126"}}]},{"parent":{"parentId":null,"parentName":null},"child":[{"parent":{"parentId":"1000657","parentName":"parent127"},"child":[{"parent":{"parentId":"1000529","parentName":"parent128"}},{"parent":{"parentId":"1000529","parentName":"parent129"}},{"parent":{"parentId":"1000529","parentName":"parent111"}},{"parent":{"parentId":"1000529","parentName":"parent100"}},{"parent":{"parentId":"1000529","parentName":"parent90"}}]},{"parent":{"parentId":"1000657","parentName":"parent91"},"child":[{"parent":{"parentId":"1000535","parentName":"parent92"}},{"parent":{"parentId":"1000535","parentName":"parent92"}},{"parent":{"parentId":"1000535","parentName":"parent92"}},{"parent":{"parentId":"1000535","parentName":"parent92"}}]},{"parent":{"parentId":"1000657","parentName":"parent234"},"child":[{"parent":{"parentId":"1000524","parentName":"parent230"}},{"parent":{"parentId":"1000524","parentName":"parent231"}},{"parent":{"parentId":"1000524","parentName":"parent232"}},{"parent":{"parentId":"1000524","parentName":"parent233"}}]},{"parent":{"parentId":"1000657","parentName":"parent234"}}]},{"parent":{"parentId":null,"parentName":null}},{"parent":{"parentId":null,"parentName":null}},{"parent":{"parentId":null,"parentName":null}},{"parent":{"parentId":null,"parentName":null}},{"parent":{"parentId":null,"parentName":null},"child":[{"parent":{"parentId":"1000611","parentName":"loan parent"},"child":[{"parent":{"parentId":"1000612","parentName":"loan"},"child":{"name":"loan1","id":"1000613","treeDepth":3}},{"parent":{"parentId":"1000612","parentName":"loan"},"child":{"name":"loan2","id":"1000615","treeDepth":3}},{"parent":{"parentId":"1000612","parentName":"loan"},"child":{"name":"loan3","id":"1000614","treeDepth":3}}]},{"parent":{"parentId":"1000611","parentName":"DIGI VAS CAY"},"child":[{"parent":{"parentId":"1000616","parentName":"bundle1"}},{"parent":{"parentId":"1000616","parentName":"bundle2"}}]}]},{"parent":{"parentId":null,"parentName":null},"child":[{"parent":{"parentId":"1000645","parentName":"parent6"},"child":[{"parent":{"parentId":"1000646","parentName":"parent8"}},{"parent":{"parentId":"1000646","parentName":"parent8"}},{"parent":{"parentId":"1000646","parentName":"parent8"}},{"parent":{"parentId":"1000646","parentName":"parent8"}}]},{"parent":{"parentId":"1000645","parentName":"parent5"},"child":[{"parent":{"parentId":"1000651","parentName":"parent6"}},{"parent":{"parentId":"1000651","parentName":"parent6"}}]},{"parent":{"parentId":"1000645","parentName":"parent5"},"child":[{"parent":{"parentId":"1000654","parentName":"parent123"}},{"parent":{"parentId":"1000654","parentName":"parent123"}}]}]}]}';

const result = JSON.parse(json, (k, v) => 
                           v?.filter?.(o => o.child?.id || o.child?.length) ?? v)

console.log( result )
```

Answer (score 0):

## Question Tip

You need to make your data the smallest possible to demonstrate your problem the array is too big and I think there is an error in the tree somewhere.

### I think this is what you want:

```js
const mockupData = [
  {
    parent: {
      parentId: null,
      parentName: null,
    },
    child: [
      {
        parent: {
          parentId: "1000641",
          parentName: "parent120",
        },
      },
      {
        parent: {
          parentId: "1000641",
          parentName: "parent121",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  // ... (rest of your data)
];

function removeDuplicates(jsonData: any[]) {
  const seen = new Set();
  return jsonData.filter((item) => {
    if (item.child) {
      item.child = removeDuplicates(item.child);
      return item.child.length > 0;
    } else if (
      item.parent &&
      item.parent.parentId !== null &&
      item.parent.parentName !== null
    ) {
      // Create a key for the innermost child excluding the 'name' property
      const key = JSON.stringify(item.parent, (k, v) =>
        k === "parentName" ? undefined : v,
      );

      // Check if we've seen this key before
      if (!seen.has(key)) {
        seen.add(key);
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  });
}

const filteredResult = removeDuplicates(mockupData);
console.log(JSON.stringify(filteredResult, null, 4));
```

### This might also work for you:

```js
function removeEntriesWithUndefinedLastLevel(arr) {
  for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (typeof arr[i] === 'object' && !Array.isArray(arr[i])) {
      // If the current element is an object (not an array)
      // Check if its properties are also objects
      const subObject = arr[i];
      const subObjectKeys = Object.keys(subObject);

      if (subObjectKeys.length === 1 && subObject[subObjectKeys[0]] === undefined) {
        // If there is only one property, and it is undefined,
        // remove this entry from the array
        arr.splice(i, 1);
      } else {
        // Recursively check the nested objects
        removeEntriesWithUndefinedLastLevel(subObjectKeys.map(key => subObject[key]));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to convert JSON into JS object. This snip of code may help you.

```
    const jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonText);

const isObject = (value) => {
    return !!(value && typeof value === "object" && !Array.isArray(value));
};


var checkRoot = function (root) {
    if (isObject(root) && !root.child) {
        return false;
    }
    if (isObject(root) && isObject(root.child)) {
        return true;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < root.child.length; i++) {

        var toKeep = checkRoot(root.child[i]);
        if (!toKeep) {
            root.child.splice(i, 1);
            i--;
        }
    }
    return !!root.child.length;
}

var startChecking = function (jsonObj) {
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.root.length; i++) {
        var toKeep = checkRoot(jsonObj.root[i]);
        if (!toKeep) {
            jsonObj.root.splice(i, 1);
            i--;
        }
    }
    return jsonObj;
}
```

as you see, checkRoot() is the recursive function on every object of main root array. so, you must call it using loop.
this code can be rewritten with more efficiency way. but it will solve your problem.